# Android App Localization

Tags: android

We need to support localization in our Android app and user should be able to change language on any screen. For example if we have ActivityA, ActivityB and ActivityC (ActivityA->ActivityB->ActivityC) and user changes language when he is on ActivityC we also need to update labels on ActivityA and ActivityB.

Is there any techniques to do so, for example using broadcast receiver to notify all open activities, or writing listener that will listen preference changes any notify about it?.

Thanks

Comment: This usually works with string.xml. U need to supply string.xml in different languages. Eg 'res/values/string.xml' is the default language where 'res/values-de/string.xml' would be the german one

Comment: I looked through the internet with the same question some weeks ago and the "best" solution I found was to restart the application after changing the language. So I decided to write a special class that resets every textview, button etc. of every known activity. The reset is relatively simple `textView.setText(R.string...)`. This will mind the current language setting. This works and there is no restart necessary, but I hope it is a better solution out there.

Comment: If you are using the Android localization mechanism, this is handled automatically by Android.

Comment: If you need to change the language **on the fly**, just set the new default locale and restart your app. This will avoid the **overkill** of going through all your Views in all your Activities.